How can I protect my Drupal Webform website from spam?
I'm using the Captcha module in the forms, but the client informed me that I'm receiving a lot of spam in the contact form submissions. How can I reduce this? And how can I test this locally before testing it in production?

There are few things you can do to stop spam in your contact form submission.

Use ban IP to ban specific IPs which are spamming your form.
Use captcha, recaptcha modules link for reference https://www.drupal4u.org/tips-and-tricks/best-drupal-captcha-modules
Restrict users to submit form only once link for reference https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251253/how-to-limit-webform-submissions-access-to-only-users-who-have-webform-submissio

Read more options at https://www.nutshell.com/blog/8-ways-to-combat-form-spam

Thank you for your response. I will look into your suggestions !
